# Failing to update the database and load a new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

Following is the code to transfer amount to a random contact. The database I'm using is `MongoDB`. So, this code is first retrieving the name and email from the database to whom the amount is being transferred, and then the input is taken for how much amount is to be transferred. Then, the button is clicked to transfer the amount, but that isn't happening. And, I get this every time I try to click on transfer button (I do have a record with the id `65506513f70aded25aefce3c` in the database):

```
PUT http://localhost:8082/api/accounts/65506513f70aded25aefce3c 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:255
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:146
httpMethod @ Axios.js:185
wrap @ bind.js:5
handleTransfer @ Transfer.jsx:37
handleClick @ index.tsx:880
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Transfer.jsx:42 Err from transferring AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

I would like to move to the processing page on clicking the button, then on successful update in the database, I'd like to move to the final page.

This is the code in the `Transfer.jsx` file.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import Navbar from "./Navbar";
    import Footer from "./Footer";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { useNavigate, useParams, Link} from "react-router-dom";
    
    function Transfer (props) {
    
        const [ account, setAccount ] = useState({});
        const [ amount, setAmount ] = useState("");
    
        const { id } = useParams();
        const navigate = useNavigate();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8082/api/accounts/${ id }`).then((res) => {
                setAccount(res.data);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error from Transfer');
            });
        }, [ id ]);
    
        const accountTransfer = (
            <>
                <div className="to-acc">
                    <h4>Account Holder: { account.name }</h4>
                    <p>Email Address: { account.email }</p>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    
        const handleTransfer = () => {
            navigate('/processing');
            const reqAmount = {
                amount: amount
            };
            axios.put(`http://localhost:8082/api/accounts/${id}`, reqAmount)
            .then((res) => {
                navigate('/transaction-done');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Err from transferring', err);
            });
        }
    
        return (
            <>
                <Navbar />
                <div className="accounts-page transfer-flex">
                    <div>{ accountTransfer }</div>
                    <img src="/../../images/exchange.png" alt="exchange" />
                </div>
                <div className="enter-amount">
                    <div>
                        <b>Enter money to transfer: </b><input type="number" value={amount} onChange={ (e) => {
                            setAmount(e.target.value)
                        }} minLength={1} maxLength={5} />
                    </div>
                    <Link onClick={handleTransfer}><button>Transfer</button></Link>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default Transfer;
```

In my routes/api directory, I have this code:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    
    const Account = require('../../models/Accounts');
    
    // retreive all accounts
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        Account.find().then(accounts => res.json(accounts)).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ noAccountFound: 'No accounts found.' }));
    });
    
    // retrieving single account
    router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
        Account.findById(req.params.id).then(account => res.json(account)).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ noAccountsFound: 'No such account found.' }));
    });
    
    // update transfering contact
    router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
        try {
          console.log('Updating account with ID:', req.params.id);
      
          if (!amount || isNaN(amount)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid amount provided' });
        }
    
        const updatedAccount = await Account.findByIdAndUpdate(
            id,
            { $inc: { balance: parseInt(amount) } }, // Increment the balance by the specified amount
            { new: true } // Return the updated document
        );
    
        if (!updatedAccount) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Account not found' });
        }
      
          res.json({ msg: 'Transaction successful!' });
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
      });  
    
    
    module.exports = router;
```

In the app.js file, I got:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const connectDB = require('./db/db');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const accounts = require('./routes/api/accounts');
    
    const app = express();
    connectDB();
    
    app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
    app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
    
    app.use('/api/accounts', accounts);
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${ port }`);
    });
```